# NxN matrix with n from user input and default values if no n provided

Tags: c#

I need to make a Jacobi Gauss program but I'm struggling with the start of it. We need to create a class which encapsulates a nxn matrix and stores it in a 2D array, with the default value being 3x3 with all values 0. We then have to add features to this and the rest of the Jacobi Gauss model. I've tried a few ways to make a matrix but I can't get one that relies on user input for size or defaults to a set size/values.

Comment: Showing the code of what you tried, with notes about where you're struggling helps give us context to provide better answers.  It also helps us guide you and teach you, instead of just providing the answer for you (since this is a learning exercise).  So consider editing your question with some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to represent 2d matrix but the most simple is just as a native 2d array.  By default a new array is filled with default values which for ints is zero. You can initialize yourself.  Or, of course you can simply set the values after you create it.

Note in the first case I've created the array based off a integer.  In this case for simplicity 1 value, obviously it does not have to be square.

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        int dimensions = 3;

        int[,] matrix = new int[dimensions, dimensions];

        foreach (var v in matrix)
            Console.WriteLine(v);

        int[,] matrix2 = new int[,] { { 1,1,1},{ 2,2,2},{ 3,3,3} };

        for (int x = 0; x < dimensions; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < dimensions; ++y)
            {
                // matrix2[x,y] = whatever...
                Console.WriteLine(matrix2[x, y]);
            }
        }
    }
```

One option to wrap this in a class is to use a indexer method.  For a simple square matrix with absolutely no error handling that might look like this:

```
public class MyMatrix
{
    int[,] data = null;
    public MyMatrix(int dims = 3)
    {
        this.data = new int[dims, dims];
    }

    public void SetDimensions(int dims)
    {
        if (this.data.GetLowerBound(0) != dims)
        {
            this.data = new int[dims, dims];
            for (int x = 0; x < dims; ++x)
                for (int y = 0; y < dims; ++y)
                    this.data[x, y] = 0;
        }
    }

    public int this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return this.data[x, y]; }
        set { this.data[x, y] = value; }
    }

    public int Size => this.data.GetLowerBound(0);
 }


    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        MyMatrix m = new MyMatrix(3);

        for (int x = 0; x < m.Size; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < m.Size; ++y)
            {
                // m[x,y] = whatever...
                Console.WriteLine(m[x, y]);
            }
        }
    }
```